# Send email after my 'TestNG' tests have fully Executed? (Email sending code works)

Tags: maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

1. So i need to send an email after every new test suite executions.
2. MVN CLEAN: deletes the 'target: surefire directory'
3. If i execute my test case, a new 'email-able report' will be created.
4. I have tried placing my send email report, in the @AfterSuite method however when the test executes it cannot find the report because only after the test suite has finished does the report generate.
5. any ideas on how to send the report after the test suite has finished, possible to use TestNG and my email method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a *SuiteListener* insteadof *@AfterSuite*:

SuiteListener.java:

```
package org.example;

import org.testng.ISuite;
import org.testng.ISuiteListener;

public class SuiteListener implements ISuiteListener {
  public void onStart(ISuite suite) {
  }

  public void onFinish(ISuite suite) {
    // send report...
  }
}
```

testng.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="TestNgMavenExampleSuite" parallel="false">
  <listeners>
    <listener class-name="org.example.SuiteListener" />
  </listeners>
  ...
</suite>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use Jenkins to executing your tests and sending email notification. Configuring that might take some time if you are doing it for the first time but it has lots of option.

however, for now you can use maven java command to execute your Java file after executing all the tests. Run this command after you **maven test** command.

```
mvn test-compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.gaurang.SendEmail" -Dexec.classpathScope="test"
```

Comment: thanks, do i need to change the following: -Dexec.mainClass="com.gaurang.SendEmail" and -Dexec.classpathScope="test"?

Comment: @Phil_P85    yes, replace **com.gaurang.SendEmail** with your full qualified class which sends email.